# running process does not follow system time

Tags: c, linux, time, timezone

Consider the following program that does nothing except print the time once a minute.
When I change /etc/localtime link to a different timezone, I want it to print the time according to the new timezone, yet it keeps using the timezone that was in effect when it started.

How do I get the program to use the correct time, even when timezone was changed while it is running?

BTW, the system is CentOS 5.8

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_STIME_LEN 32
int
main()
{
    while(1){
        struct timeval timev;
        gettimeofday(&timev,0);
        struct tm now_tm;
        time_t now = timev.tv_sec;
        char saved_time[MAX_STIME_LEN];
        strftime(saved_time, sizeof(saved_time), "%b %e %T", localtime_r (&now, &now_tm));
        printf("%s\n",saved_time);
        sleep(15);
    }
}
```

Please note that the use of localtime_r and strftime rather then using a ons-stop call, is necessary. This is just an example.

Comment: Adding tzset() before the call to localtime_r(), AND making sure TZ is not set when the program starts, fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer here: stackoverflow.com/questions/19170721/…, all it was missing is that I had to unset the environment variable TZ (even though it was simply pointing to /etc/localtime)